# JSP - Running a program with main method and nested static class

Tags: java, jsp

I'm a novice when it comes to JSPs and JAVA.

How do I get the output from the below code to display on a jsp, considering that it runs everything from the main and contains non-public methods, a nested static class etc?

I know that we are not supposed to use java code on jsp but my first step in this proof on concept exercise is to get the code running and returning data from a backend then I can set about using EL etc.

I can run the program, with the correct config settings, from within Eclipse and all works fine with the output appearing on the console but I'm really not sure how to access it from within a jsp.

How do I access the static class and static methods from a jsp if they aren't public?

All help greatly appreciated.

```
public class CustomDestinationDataProvider
{

static class MyDestinationDataProvider implements DestinationDataProvider
{
    private DestinationDataEventListener eL;
    private HashMap<String, Properties> secureDBStorage = new HashMap<String, Properties>();

    public Properties getDestinationProperties(String destinationName)
    {
        try
        {
            //read the destination from DB
            Properties p = secureDBStorage.get(destinationName);

            if(p!=null)
            {
                //check if all is correct, for example
                if(p.isEmpty())
                    throw new DataProviderException(DataProviderException.Reason.INVALID_CONFIGURATION, "destination configuration is incorrect", null);

                return p;
            }

            return null;
        }
        catch(RuntimeException re)
        {
            throw new DataProviderException(DataProviderException.Reason.INTERNAL_ERROR, re);
        }
    }

    public void setDestinationDataEventListener(DestinationDataEventListener eventListener)
    {
        this.eL = eventListener;
    }

    public boolean supportsEvents()
    {
        return true;
    }

    //implementation that saves the properties in a very secure way
    void changeProperties(String destName, Properties properties)
    {
        synchronized(secureDBStorage)
        {
            if(properties==null)
            {
                if(secureDBStorage.remove(destName)!=null)
                    eL.deleted(destName);
            }
            else 
            {
                secureDBStorage.put(destName, properties);
                eL.updated(destName); // create or updated
            }
        }
    }
} // end of MyDestinationDataProvider

//business logic
void executeCalls(String destName)
{
    JCoDestination dest;
    try
    {
        dest = JCoDestinationManager.getDestination(destName);
        dest.ping();
        System.out.println("Destination " + destName + " works");
        step4WorkWithTable(dest);
        }
    catch(JCoException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Execution on destination " + destName+ " failed");
    }
}

static Properties getDestinationPropertiesFromUI()
{
    //adapt parameters in order to configure a valid destination
    Properties connectProperties = new Properties();
    // Add code here to set config settings
    return connectProperties;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    MyDestinationDataProvider myProvider = new MyDestinationDataProvider();

    //register the provider with the JCo environment;
    //catch IllegalStateException if an instance is already registered
    try
    {
        com.sap.conn.jco.ext.Environment.registerDestinationDataProvider(myProvider);
    }
    catch(IllegalStateException providerAlreadyRegisteredException)
    {
        //somebody else registered its implementation, 
        //stop the execution
        throw new Error(providerAlreadyRegisteredException);
    }

    String destName = "????";
    CustomDestinationDataProvider test = new CustomDestinationDataProvider();

    //set properties for the destination and ...
    myProvider.changeProperties(destName, getDestinationPropertiesFromUI());
    //... work with it
    test.executeCalls(destName);


}


public static void step4WorkWithTable(JCoDestination dest) throws JCoException
{
    JCoFunction function = dest.getRepository().getFunction("BAPI_COMPANYCODE_GETLIST");
    if(function == null)
        throw new RuntimeException("BAPI_COMPANYCODE_GETLIST not found in SAP.");

    try
    {
        function.execute(dest);
    }
    catch(AbapException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        return;
    }

    JCoStructure returnStructure = function.getExportParameterList().getStructure("RETURN");
    if (! (returnStructure.getString("TYPE").equals("")||returnStructure.getString("TYPE").equals("S"))  )   
    {
       throw new RuntimeException(returnStructure.getString("MESSAGE"));
    }

    JCoTable codes = function.getTableParameterList().getTable("COMPANYCODE_LIST");
    for (int i = 0; i < codes.getNumRows(); i++) 
    {
        codes.setRow(i);
        System.out.println(codes.getString("COMP_CODE") + '\t' + codes.getString("COMP_NAME"));
    }

    //move the table cursor to first row
    codes.firstRow();
    for (int i = 0; i < codes.getNumRows(); i++, codes.nextRow()) 
    {
        function = dest.getRepository().getFunction("BAPI_COMPANYCODE_GETDETAIL");
        if (function == null) 
            throw new RuntimeException("BAPI_COMPANYCODE_GETDETAIL not found in SAP.");

        function.getImportParameterList().setValue("COMPANYCODEID", codes.getString("COMP_CODE"));

        //We do not need the addresses, so set the corresponding parameter to inactive.
        //Inactive parameters will be  either not generated or at least converted.  
        function.getExportParameterList().setActive("COMPANYCODE_ADDRESS",false);

        try
        {
            function.execute(dest);
        }
        catch (AbapException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            return;
        }

        returnStructure = function.getExportParameterList().getStructure("RETURN");
        if (! (returnStructure.getString("TYPE").equals("") ||
               returnStructure.getString("TYPE").equals("S") ||
               returnStructure.getString("TYPE").equals("W")) ) 
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(returnStructure.getString("MESSAGE"));
        }

        JCoStructure detail = function.getExportParameterList().getStructure("COMPANYCODE_DETAIL");

        System.out.println(detail.getString("COMP_CODE") + '\t' +
                           detail.getString("COUNTRY") + '\t' +
                           detail.getString("CITY"));
    }//for
}            
}
```

Comment: Take about 20 steps back. Just get a simple _string_ to show on your JSP. You seem to be wanting to do everything at once. Where is your controller code? Are you using any MVC Frameworks? Have you written anything at all pertaining to the controller/jsp?

Comment: To add, I believe the static class is irrelevant. It seems your real question is how to get values from Java code to display in your JSP. The source of the data doesn't matter.

Comment: If I instantiate on the jsp, is the main automatically triggered?

Comment: i.e. <% CustomerDestinationDataProvider custDest = new CustomDestinationDataProvider(); %>

Comment: @Christopher Schneider I have created a dynamic web app in Eclipse and included the above source code. I have yet to create any controller code or servlets.

Comment: The solution was to create another class and instantiate the above class within it and use the second class on the jsp